# How to set the hostname and private key of an X509Certificate2 object? (.NET4.6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, client-certificates

I have to consume an API that requires a mTLS certificate. There is a .crt, .key files and a hostname. The key is a private key that starts with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"...

In postman I did this and it did worked:

[Postman print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgeoV.png)

My code is like this now:

```
string privateKey = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\privatekey.key");

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\somefile.crt");

// Add the key and the hostname?

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

How/Where can I add the key and the "host-name.com"?

Comment: If you're using .NET 5 or newer: `X509Certificate2 certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(@"D:\somefile.crt", @"D:\privatekey.key");`.  As for the hostname: it was either decided in advance for the certificate, or you mean something else that I don't understand.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set the project to .NET 5, it must to be running with .NET 4.6, but thank you.